# Guide for Installing Java Platform, Enterprise Edition

Tags: java

Recently I have been searching for Java EE programs, and i found so many downloadables in the link below. Which is the right option to download to start making Java EE programs?

Is JDK a system requirements for Java EE?

Do we need to install Glassfish to make Java EE programs? Can we use IDE instead of Glassfish to make Java EE programs? Or can we just use Notepad, compile, and execute the program the usual way (javac and java in Command Prompt)?

Here's the link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-ee-glance.html

Comment: There is no one "right" option. Java EE encompases many disparate useful things (which are documented at the link you provided). A JDK is a requirement for Java development. A JRE is generally used for running Java programs. Glassfish is one Java EE application server (not a development tool). WildFly is another. Eclipse, NetBeans and intelliJ are examples of IDEs that can be used to write Java EE programs. Using Notepad would be **beyond** tedious to track dependencies in a Java EE program. But it's 100% possible.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So, in order to make Java EE programs we need to install an IDE, is that so?

Comment: I said it was 100% possible to write a Java EE program using Notepad. I have done it (I used vim but that is also just a text editor). I would not recommend it. The quality of IDEs and the power of modern cpus has rendered the concept of reverting to a text editor unappealing. I have also been working in this space before Sun chose to name it Java EE (we started with EJBs on Tengah, but you probably don't want a history lesson).

Answer (score 4):

## Jakarta EE

Java EE, or [*Java Platform, Enterprise Edition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Enterprise_Edition), has been turned over by [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation), and is now released as *Jakarta® EE*. See the [jakarta.ee](http://Jakarta%C2%AE%20EE) web site.

- Jakarta EE 8 is the same as Oracle’s Java EE 8, after having been brought over to the source code, build, and documentation infrastructure housed at the Eclipse Foundation.
- Jakarta EE 9 represents pretty much the same content as Jakarta EE 8, but has new naming and packaging to eliminate the use of branding and trademarks owned by Oracle.
- Jakarta EE 10 will be the first to have major new features and innovations, as discussed on [this blog post](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2020/may/1.php).

Keep in mind that there is no one thing that is "EE". We are talking about **a bunch of specifications** for a bunch of features that are commonly of interest to those building apps in an enterprise environment. To avoid a hodgepodge mess of various incompatible product offerings, the various vendors teamed together to define some standard specifications. No one team uses all of these specs and features. No one product implements all of these specs and features. Some specs and features have been newly added, and some are fading away from disuse. So look through the [list of specs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) to see what might apply to your work, and then obtain a product that implements those particular specs.

Some of the Jakarta EE specs require an [app server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server), such as [Servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) and Web Services. Some do not, such as [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org) and the [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)/[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) processing/binding, which can be used with regular Java SE based apps.

Here is a diagram of mine showing various technologies of Java SE and EE. This chart is a bit out-of-date, but gives you a rough idea of what is involved.

[image: Nested diagrams listing technologies found in Java SE & EE.]

You asked:

> Is JDK a system requirements for Java EE?

Yes.

[Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Standard_Edition) (standard edition) is the foundation of Jakarta EE. Jakarta EE is a big collection of specifications for software built on top of Java SE, and deployed on top of Java SE.

So you must obtain an implementation of Java SE (a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)) in order to do Jakarta EE development and deployment.

You have a wide choice of vendors for obtaining a JDK. Here is a flowchart I made to help guide you in making that choice.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

You asked:

> Do we need to install Glassfish to make Java EE programs?

Glassfish is one of several implementations of Jakarta EE. See [this list](https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/) of some of those implementations, or see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_application_servers#Java) on Wikipedia. Others include [Eclipse Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)) & [Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), and [Apache TomEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_TomEE) is another.

By the way, Glassfish is a free-of-cost open-source project that comes without support. Payara is a commercial product based on Glassfish that offers support. Similarly, Red Hat publishes WildFly as a free-of-cost open-source project, on which their commercial JBoss product is based. So be aware of cost, terms of licensing, and support plans as you choose a product that fits your needs.

Remember, Jakarta EE is a collection of [*specifications*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_(technical_standard)), not a collection of software source code or binaries.

> Can we use IDE instead of Glassfish to make Java EE programs? Or can we just use Notepad, compile, and execute the program the usual way (javac and java in Command Prompt)?

Orthogonal issues.

You must choose an implementation of Jakarta EE that has the features you need (not all products implement all of the wide array of specs defined in Jakarta EE). You will be obtaining software that provides the services promised by the specs. *Glassfish* is just one of several implementations of various Jakarta EE technologies.

How you write your program is up to you. You write code that calls upon the software in whichever implementation you obtain. You can write that code in [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor) or in an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). Practically speaking, I believe you will find an IDE indispensable. The main ones nowadays are IntelliJ, Eclipse, and NetBeans. All three are very popular, very powerful, awkwardly designed, and come with a learning curve.

### Baby steps first

Some advice… Sounds like you are new to Java. I suggest you focus on just Java SE, and forget about the EE stuff while getting started. Do some simple Hello World tutorials, such as the free-of-cost [tutorials provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Get used to Java classes, methods, compilers, building JAR files, JDKs, and [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)s. Then move on to learning about EE specs and implementations.

As an analogy, you are asking about professional race car driving à la [Paul Newman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Newman#Auto_racing), but you have not yet gotten your Driver's Permit à la [Doogie Howser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doogie_Howser%2C_M.D.).

Comment: Twenty years of EE specs and implementations. Forget the firehose, it's like trying to sip from Niagara Falls. I started with EJB and JMS and then realized I would need a few paragraphs just to introduce those. It's not a small question.

Comment: I have nothing to add, just want to show my appreciation for a great answer!